# What will happen if GIO meet STD::IO?

Tags: c++, g++, glib

I create a g_main_loop in main thread. 
And watch the IO by 'g_io_add_watch'.
Then, the std::cin() and scanf() can get nothing. Why is that?

Run & Input:

> abc

Then output:

> +++ enter into foo()
>   +++ get string in foo:
>   +++ get char[] in foo:

It just skip the std::cin and scanf.

Code as following:

'''

```
static void foo()
{
    printf("+++ enter into foo()\n");
    std::string str;
    cin >> str;
    printf("+++ get string in foo: %s\n", str.c_str());

    char ss[128] = {0x00, };
    scanf("%s", ss);
    printf("+++ get char[] in foo: %s\n", ss);
}

static gboolean handle_keyboard(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition cond,  gpointer data)
{
  g_io_channel_read_line(source, &str, &len, NULL, NULL);
  switch(g_ascii_tolower(str[0]))
  {
  case 'a':
    foo();
    break;
  }
  ...
  return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
  //...
  g_io_add_watch(io_stdin, G_IO_IN, (GIOFunc)handle_keyboard, NULL);
  //...
}
```

'''

Comment: presumably gio is taking all the input, you need to use gio functions to read it rather than stdio

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, stdio is used by an elder SDK. And I am going to invoke this SDK in my project, which uses GIO. It will change a lot, either for each one.